# Advanced progress calculation

Tags: progress-bar

Hello i am developing an automatic update system which has a progress bar which is staged based.

```
detecting connection = 10%
checking file exists = 20%
check for updates = 30%
download update = 40%-70%
install update = 70%-100%
```

This is where it gets complicated, once the progress bar has reached the download update stage i would like the progress bar to also show the progress of the download which would mean the following...

```
40% = 0% of the download
70% = 100% of the download
```

and once the download is complete...

```
70% = 0% of the update installed
100% = 100% of the update installed
```

but how would this be calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`70 - 40 = 30`, so 30% of the bar represents your download progress

`30 / 100 = 0.3`, so increment by 0.3 % each time 1% of the download completes.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to crack it, the formula was: **40+downloaded/total*30**, thanks for your help, i really apperciate it

Comment: I changed the math from `100 - 70` to `70 - 40` after I realized I misread your question. Still 30% dedicated to downloading though :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the download progress (as a fraction between 0 and 1), multiply it by 30, and add it to the base number (40 or 70).

My open-source [Progression library](https://github.com/SLaks/Progression/) (C#) can do this for you by creating a [scaled child reporter](https://github.com/SLaks/Progression/wiki/Child-Reporters).